# Java posting to http fields/form keeps failing

Tags: java, html, http, networking

Ok so I have tried a lot of stuff including sockets,httpConnection,httpClients,proxies,using cookies,and wide array of other things but this just keeps failing.What I need my program to do is send some data to html site and then recive adquate response.But resposne is always exact opposite of what I am expection.To be little more specific site I am talking about is http://hidemyass.com and I need to set the field value to "http://reddit.com" whos name is u and then press the button witch will redirect to Reddit through a proxy.So in theory response I should get is the Reddit html source or regular server response.But what I keep getting is http://hidemyass.com html source code with default values set(aka as I have not sent those values over a connection to it).

So here is what I did and it did not work.

CODE:

```
//I will skip used import because I think they are not of importance
//Also try catch blocks will be skipped and not written

private static UrlEncodedFormEntity entity;

public static void main(String[] args){

    HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
    ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> params=new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("u","http://reddit.com");
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hmabutton,"Hide My Ass");
    entity=new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,null)//there is no encoding on this site
    HttpPost post=new HttpPost("http://hidemyass.com");
    post.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response=client.execute(post);
    HttpEntity ent=response.getEntity();
    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(ent));
}
```

Can anyone help me see my error finally and get the site to do what I want?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending HTTP POST Request In Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java)

Comment: Please elaborate on: "get the site to do what I want".

Answer (score 0):

You must post your request to the form's action URL:

```
HttpPost post=new HttpPost("http://hidemyass.com/process.php");
```