# How to parse XML generated by a servlet

Tags: java, xml, parsing, servlets, xml-parsing

this is my simple Java servlet which generate XML code retreiving it from a simple database:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*

@WebServlet("/XML")
public class XML extends HttpServlet {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public XML() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Connection connection;
    Statement statement;

    response.setContentType("application/xml");
    PrintWriter printwriter = response.getWriter();

    printwriter.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>");
    printwriter.println("<document>");

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/AppDB", "***", "****");

        statement = connection.createStatement();

        String SQL = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM contacts";
        ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery(SQL);

        while(resultset.next()) {
            printwriter.println("<first> " +  resultset.getString("first_name") + " </first>");
            printwriter.println("<last> " +  resultset.getString("last_name") + " </last>");
        }
        resultset.close();
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
    printwriter.println("</document>");
    printwriter.close();
}

}
```

Now, I want to parse it on client-side for displaying data but I don't know how to do that. I have tried to use a JSP file with the SAX parser but when the server give me a error when I put the following Servlet URL:

```
Document doc = docBuilder.parse("http://localhost:8080/Example/XML");
```

Could anyone please help me giving me some advice to solve the problem?
And could anyone know a possible alternative way to do the same thing? What about JQuery or Ajax? (Even if I have just read a few thing about it, but I don't know them very well)

Comment: Looks like XML is a directory not an .xml file, pass the full path to the xml file you are trying to parse.

Comment: you have written the xml generation in the doPost() method. If you want to get the xml response just by passing the URL try the implementation in doGet() method

Comment: @Prabhakaran Thanks a lot! Perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

**Choose between POST or GET**

**GET** => use docBuilder.parse like that, and code doGet in your app.

You can just redirect to doPost

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
doPost (request,response);
}
```

**POST** => dont change you servlet, but change your client.

**1. docBuilder with URL works also like that, but with GET by default:**

```
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new URL("http://localhost:8080/Example/XML").openStream());
```

see that: [How to read XML response from a URL in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310139/how-to-read-xml-response-from-a-url-in-java)

**2. So change to POST**

use

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/Example/XML");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
InputStream is= connection.getInputStream();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(is);
```

but beware: if you want to pass datas, you have to put in before:

```
OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
out.write(parameters and data here);
out.close();
```

see that: 
[How can I send POST data through url.openStream()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804511/how-can-i-send-post-data-through-url-openstream)

[How to read XML response from a URL in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310139/how-to-read-xml-response-from-a-url-in-java)

[Sending HTTP POST Request In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java)