# JAVA sending POST http request

Tags: java, http, post, request

I want to send post request programaticaly, using URL and inputStream so I can read output. I dont know at all how to start, I tried two other topics form SO but none worked... I dont want to use Apache client.

Thanx for replies.

Comment: *Why* don't you want to use HttpClient, what *exactly* have you tried, and what happened. It's very hard to answer such a vague question.

Comment: I dont want to use becouse I dont want to be dependent on their software, I tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java and one more SO topic that I cant find now.

Comment: See this thread in SO [How to use http url connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests) Study it (BalusC answer is **really** awsome!) and you should be ok.

Comment: What you actually looking for ? Post request with URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the HttpURLConnection class

heres a link to the javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#method

heres an example i found http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139

Hope it works