# How can I INSERT into fusion tables with javascript without authentication?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I'd like to create a basic form that, when submitted, sends a POST request to fusion tables to INSERT the data as a new row. I'd like it to be open to the public so anyone can submit the form. It seems like to do an INSERT I need to use OAuth, so the users will need to login with their google account to fill out the form. (Similar to Application 1 in [the docs](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/articles/oauthfusiontables))

Is there a way to let users submit the form without requiring them to login? Perhaps getting a pre-generated token/secret that lets them submit to this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this use case you should use [Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount), which act as some kind of deputy for the user. It is a technical user under your control and with permissions on the corresponding table.

See also my answers to similar questions in the past: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11893279/549755) and [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11619373/549755)

Comment: Interesting. So if I'm reading your comments correctly, it looks like no matter what, I'll have to use some server side code?

Comment: As of now, this is correct, yes. At least to retrieve the access_token, everything else can be done via client-side JavaScript.