# Insert Into fusion table using javascript and oauth2

Tags: insert, client, oauth-2.0, google-fusion-tables

Please check http://www.udayan2k12.com/trial.html

I have just copied the source from Google link (Source)
Original Page [link](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontables/javascript-api.html)
I have changed the client id and api key
Still this is not working

My Cliend ID details are ![enter image description here][1]

Client ID:  365219651081-istfrdgsvrtj324sufau0ldi5e8b3fmk.apps.googleusercontent.com
Email address:  365219651081-istfrdgsvrtj324sufau0ldi5e8b3fmk@developer.gserviceaccount.com
Client secret:  --
Redirect URIs:  none
JavaScript origins: https://www[dot]udayan2k12[dot]com
API key:    AIzaSyA0FVy-lEr_MPGk1p_lHSrxGZDcxy6wH4o

What Changes shall i do to make it work.
The Authorize button doesn't work.

But it works in http://udayan2k12[dot]com/token.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the error console you'll see that you get the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=365219651081-istfrdgsvrtj324sufau0ldi5e8b3fmk.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Ffusiontables&immediate=true&redirect_uri=postmessage&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.udayan2k12.com&proxy=oauth2relay665167919&response_type=token&state=225646027&authuser=0
```

And when you follow the [link](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=365219651081-istfrdgsvrtj324sufau0ldi5e8b3fmk.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables&immediate=true&redirect_uri=postmessage&origin=http://www.udayan2k12.com&proxy=oauth2relay665167919&response_type=token&state=225646027&authuser=0), the error message you get is: `origin_mismatch`

This means you did not add **http://udayan2k12.com** (and not *https*) to the allowed JavaScript origins for your client id. You can change that on the [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) (Tab "API Access"). You could add localhost as well so it works on you machine, too.

Here is an example of my settings:

[image: My client id settings]

Please check the [OAuth 2.0 guide from Google](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) for all the steps you need.

Comment: Thanks u r a lifesaver :-) i was using https instead of http :0