# Data insertion to FusionTables programmatically

Tags: c#, javascript, google-fusion-tables

How to insert data into my fusion table through coding like (JavaScript, C# )?
Normally, when we have data, we can insert it into fusion table manually by creating a .csv file and import it as new rows. But, the data that I am dealing with is online so I can't upload data to my fusion tables manually every time.

So, I would like to do it programmatically either by using JavaScript or C#. I have created a Google account, a csv table in Google FusionTables and an authentication key for my site to access it. But I don't know how to implement all these in order to upload data to my table FusionTables.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Google Fusion Table API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/getting_started).

There are a lot of examples around, I recommend to use one of the [Google API client libraries](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/libraries) that are available for many different languages, including [JavaScript](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/) and [.NET (C#)](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/).

I already [answered a similar question about a JavaScript-only solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11619373/549755) some time ago.