# How to send a HTTP POST request using HttpClient 4 in Java?

Tags: java, http, post, file-upload

So I've struggling with this one lately. There are multiple ways to make a HTTP POST request with Java, some of which demonstrate with `HttpClient` 3.x and the others with `HttpClient` 4.x

I'm assuming that the 4.x line is more advanced, but there are also lacking tutorials with this one. At least for me, I had hard time to find some beginner friendly guides.

I'd like to make a POST request with an encoded `File` object.

Some of the tutorials I've followed also mentioned `NameValuePair`, but for me this class is not available and I don't know how to obtain it. So if you answer, please mention how I can get hold of the imports as well.

Please demonstrate a minimal HTTP POST request with `HttpClient` 4.x

Comment: `NameValuePair` is in the same library as `HttpClient`, that is [the HTTP components httpclient](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient).

Comment: Also, to send a POST with a file, you'll want to do a multipart request. You can do that with [`MultipartEntityBuilder`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntityBuilder.html) which is part of [mime](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime).

Comment: Check this example which uses Apache's library http://evgenyg.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/uploading-files-multipart-post-apache/

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I can't seem to have that figured out. What's the actual import for this?

Comment: `org.apache.http.NameValuePair` and its basic sub type `org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair`. Don't use this for file uploads.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks. What should be used for file uploads instead?

Comment: See my second comment.

Comment: Take a look at this Post. It should explain things to you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java