# How to submit a post request to a form?

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient, http-post

Here is the [test form](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_method)

Let's say i need to submit first name `x` and last name `y` . So , I can submit the `get` request simply by entering the following `url`

```
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/demo_form_method.asp?fname=x&lname=y
```

Now, if I change `method="post"` then the above method does not work. How can I submit the `post` request programatically and then `print` the resulting page to `console`  ?

---

I tried to use many methods . For example

```
PostMethod post = new PostMethod("http://www.w3schools.com/tags/demo_form_method.asp");
        NameValuePair[] data = {
          new NameValuePair("fname", "x"),
          new NameValuePair("lname", "y")
        };
        post.setRequestBody(data);

        ...
        InputStream in = post.getResponseBodyAsStream();
```

Comment: The above doesn't work because you have to send the parameters as content of body of the request. Please provide the code you're using to start the request, otherwise this question is not Java at all.

Comment: In a POST, the parameters are sent as the *body* of the request.

Comment: I added one of my attempts.

Comment: Well, seems that the URL doesn't support POST requests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see that your test form that doesn't support "post" method. I pasted the form snippet below

```
    <form action="demo_form_method.asp" **method="get"** target="_blank">
```

There is a lot of help on the Internet on how does form works for post method and how can one send the "post" requests through java.

Some random references below :

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.1

http://alien.dowling.edu/~vassil/tutorials/javapost.php

HTH