# How to retrieve JSON from HTTP POST request in Java?

Tags: java, php, json, rest, post

So I've created a basic REST API in PHP that returns the following:

```
$result = array(
    "var" => 'testvalue',
);

sendResponse(200, json_encode($result));
```

How would I get this `testvalue` from the JSON using a HTTP POST request in Java?

I'm using the recommended answer from here currently: [Sending HTTP POST Request In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java)

But it dosn't show how to convert it from this stage:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
```

To a Java object.

So pretty much how to convert from JSON to a Java object.

Any ideas?

Comment: So do you want JSON data format to PHP ?

Comment: Why JSON is unusable format?

Comment: What do you mean by "*But it dosn't show how to convert it from JSON to a usable format in Java*"? Can you include example of results you get and what you would like to achieve?

Comment: So you are asking how to convert JSON string to Java objects ?

Comment: @user3420034 you can use GSON or Jackson.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java/1688182#1688182

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need to read large data, you can use something like:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
String var = json.getString("var"):
```

You can use it on Android too, the library is `org.json.JSONObject`.

Comment: It could be nice to mention from which library/package JSONObject comes from because it is not standard Java class.

Comment: @Pshemo org.json.JSONObject

Comment: It would be nice if you put that information with appropriate link to project site or jars (and/or maven dependency) to your answer.