# Sending data from java to php file

Tags: java, php, android

I want to post this data in database through php file. Right now, Username,Company , Shares and Date are posted in database. I want to post "Edward", "AHCL", "10" and "23-04-2015"

```
public void Insert(View view){

          String UserName="Edward";

         //String Company = company.getText().toString();
         // Shares = shares.getText().toString();
         // String Date = date.getText().toString();

          String Company = "AHCL";
          String Shares= "10";
          String Date= "23-04-2015";


      try {
            // open a connection to the site
            URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080//test/example.php");
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
            // activate the output
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream());
            // send your parameters to your site
            ps.print("&Username=Username");
            ps.print("&Company=Company");               
            ps.print("&Shares=Shares");
            ps.print("&Date=Date");

            // we have to get the input stream in order to actually send the request
            con.getInputStream();

            // close the print stream
            ps.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }







         // creating new product in background thread
         //new CreatePortfolio().execute();
     }
```

Comment: See: [How to connect Android with PHP, MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try and change

```
 ps.print("&Username=Username");
    ps.print("&Company=Company");               
    ps.print("&Shares=Shares");
    ps.print("&Date=Date");
```

to

```
 ps.print("&Username=" + Username);
    ps.print("&Company=" + Company);               
    ps.print("&Shares=" + Shares);
    ps.print("&Date=" + Date);
```

Comment: No problem, I always see these other guys on here over complicate things, I mainly do PHP work, so I go for easiest way, not the hardest most coded way. Glad it worked out for you..

Comment: I have another problem too. In my php file I am running this query.
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Company,Shares,Date FROM portfolio WHERE Username='edward") or die(mysql_error());
Now instead of edward I want to pass a variable and retrieve rows when the username will be that variable value.

Comment: You should use mysqli instead of mysql, it's the newest form. But this might help you get started. $USER_NAME = $_REQUEST['username']; $Q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `portfolio` WHERE `Username` = '$USER_NAME'"); if(mysqli_num_rows($Q) > 0)
 {
  //echo "Username already exists";
 }
 else
 { do code }               This box is making it hard to show all the correct coding, so if you can't make it out, post a link to a new question and I can put it all over there.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider sending a GET or POST request to your PHP page.
Check out how to send a POST request here: [Sending HTTP POST Request In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java)

Your PHP script can then get the value of your variables in the following using:

```
$_POST['Username']
```

Comment: I tried using that method but I was getting alot of errors through that method so I switched to this method. Isn't there any way to send variable data using this method?

Comment: You are overcomplicating your problem. Try running the Java HTTP POST request code in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Building on the code to make it complete ie passing(post) data from JAVA to PHP ,fetching and displaying in both cases.
JAVA side

```
      String UserName="Edward";
      String Company = "AHCL";
      String Shares= "10";
      String Date= "23-04-2015";

  try {
        // open a connection to the site
        URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080//test/example.php");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        // activate the output
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream());
        // send your parameters to your site
        ps.print("&Username=" + Username);
        ps.print("&Company=" + Company);               
        ps.print("&Shares=" + Shares);
        ps.print("&Date=" + Date);


        // we have to get the input stream in order to actually send the request
        con.getInputStream();
        // print out to confirm
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        // close the print stream
        ps.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }







     // creating new product in background thread
     //new CreatePortfolio().execute();
```

PHP

```
<?php 
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    switch ($key) {
        case 'firstKey':
             $Username = $value;
            break;
        case 'secondKey':
            $Company = $value;
            break;
    case 'thirdKey':
              $Shares= $value;
            break;
        case 'fourthKey':
            $Date = $value; 
            
$file = fopen("data.txt","a"); 
$details=$Username."\t".$Company."\t".$Shares."\t".$Date;
fwrite($file,$details."\n");
fclose($file);
       break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
?>
```