# java jackson send pojo as param to rest web service (json) using URLConnection

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jackson, pojo

I'm using this to **get** pojo result from web service returning json:

```
String wsURI = "server.com/myservice?param=a";
try {
    URL url = new URL(wsURI);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ResultPojo resultPojo = mapper.readValue(connection.getInputStream(), ResultPojo.class);
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

But now I want to **send** pojo to the webservice (the web service accepting json):

String wsURI = "server.com/myservice?**param=myPojo**";

How to achieve this? Is it possible or do I need to use some other libs & jars?

Thanks,

Comment: What are you intending to do with the POJO query the backend using it or set it? If set it, use POST/PUT.

Comment: @UriShalit How to add this to the code in this tools?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java

Comment: I absolutely have to compose a song called "Java Jackson Send Pojo as Param" because that would be such a catchy title.