# Java Post Data HttpsUrlConnection or HttpClient 4.5

Tags: java, post, apache-httpclient-4.x, httpsurlconnection

I am trying to do what I thought was a simple task. I need to POST data to a PHP server. I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3325065/3852863) but in Apache HttpClient 4.5 I can't find BasicNameValuePair in the package. Upon further research I thought I'd try StringEntity...nope not in 4.5 either (that I can find at least). So I tried to do it with HttpsURLConnection. The problem with that is I can't figure out how to add a name to my parameter and with a name, I don't know how to access in PHP with $_POST['name'].

My Current Code:

```
String json = gson.toJson(data);
URL url = new URL("https://www.domain.com/test.php");

HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(json.length()));
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(json.getBytes());

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String decodedString;
while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(decodedString);
}
in.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DataOutputStream and flush it afterward.

```
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeChars(json);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
```