# Java http Post request

Tags: java, http

How can i make a request for this format in java:

POST URL http/1.1

**Headers:**
Host ... 
Accept... 
...... More headers
......
**Request body**
send = ..... some data

I tryied this code with my headers and body, but it doesn't work

```
String urlParameters  = "send = .....";
byte[] postData       = urlParameters.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
int    postDataLength = postData.length;
String request        = "http://example.com/index.php";
URL    url            = new URL( request );
HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
conn.setDoOutput( true );
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
conn.setUseCaches( false );
try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream())) {
   wr.write( postData );
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: Did you **flush** the data  `wr.flush();` ?

Comment: No, but It's not transmitting  to the server request body

Comment: I caught this request in Fiddler web debugger, and when i send this request from this program it works,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending HTTP POST Request In Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java)

Comment: Maybe you'd be better off using [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) which contains a http client class.