# Groovy rest api for Dropbox without third party plugins/libraries

Tags: api, rest, grails, groovy, dropbox

I am trying to create a groovy script that will, based on some conditions, delete a dropbox folder full of artifacts.

I have been struggling to understand/figure out how to use Groovy restful API's without installing a bunch of Grails libraries or plugins, or the Dropbox API library from github.

Is it possible to use this dropbox URL: https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/fileops/delete_folder
without downloading extra libraries?

I'm having a lot of trouble finding information on the subject without the use of additional software.

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending HTTP POST Request In Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily create your own dropbox client from scratch but it is easier to check [hints](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/java) for JAVA developers and github repo with [dropbox-sdk-core](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java), which is already implementing dropbox API.

Remember to check out [examples](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/tree/master/examples) on github.