# UrlEncodedFormEntity not working as expected

Tags: java, http-post, httpclient

I am trying to make a POST request in java, and this is not working as expected.

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3325065/1790644), here is the code that I currently have

```
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data, Consts.UTF_8);
```

What I can not understand, is that while debugging this, `data`, is an `ArrayList<NameValuePair>` which the debugger shows a value of

> [Content-Type=text/json, Authorization=Bearer bZXL7hwy5vo7YnbiiGogKy6WTyCmioi8]

Which is completely expected, where I am at a complete loss, is that after this call, the value of entity is,

> [Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8,Content-Length: 78,Chunked: false]

The call has done absolutely nothing but ignore the data I passed it.

What have I done wrong here?

**Edit**

More Code

*Caller*

```
    String authURL = "https://api.ecobee.com/1/thermostat";
    authURL += "?format=json&body=" + getSelection();

    // request headers
    ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content-Type", "text/json"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Authorization", "Bearer " + code));

    // make the api call
    String apiResponse = HttpUtils.makeRequest(RequestMethod.POST, authURL, nvps);
```

*makeRequest* method

```
public static String makeRequest(RequestMethod method, String url, ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> data) {

    try {

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpRequestBase request = null;

        switch (method) {

        case POST:

            // new post request
            request = new HttpPost(url);

            // encode the post data
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data, Consts.UTF_8); // <-- this is where I have the issue
            ((HttpPost) request).setEntity(entity);
            break;

            ...
```

Comment: Some checklists : 1) Is data in the list of type BasicNameValuePair and 2) Is Consts.UTF_8 = 'utf-8'

Comment: Yes to both, This is using `httpclient` version `4.5.2`.

Comment: Can you share where exactly you are saving this entity . Can you please paste that piece of code please

Comment: I am sure .setHeader("Content-type", "application/json") will be able to resolve the issue.

Comment: I have gone ahead and added more code

Comment: If i run this command using CURL i get the expected results from the API endpoint

Comment: Can you add request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");request.setHeader("Authorization","Bearer bZXL7hwy5vo7YnbiiGogKy6WTyCmioi8"); to your code and let me know if it works.

Comment: woohoo!! thanks for this, that WAS infact the issue, I was trying to pass headers as data - i have altered my method to take a separate array list of headers, and now it is working as expected, thanks! ( If you post as an answer, I will accept ).

Comment: Great! It will be great to accept my answer so that it help others who get the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, the reason it was not working is headers should be set directly in the request instead of entity.

So you can use something like below:

```
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data, Consts.UTF_8);

request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
request.setHeader("Authorization","Bearer bZXL7hwy5vo7YnbiiGogKy6WTyCmioi8");

request.setEntity(entity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Content-Type/Authorization are headers, so should be passed using setHeader() as suggested in comments.

update: Content-Type should be *application/json* instead of *text/json*.

Instead of UrlEncodedFormEntity/BasicNameValuePair you should use StringEntity and pass the result of your getSelection() there.