# Java Server -- send Push with POST to google Firebase Cloud

Tags: java, angularjs, firebase, http-post, firebase-cloud-messaging

After I tested the push notifications are working with Postman I'd like to send a push request to FCM when I am sending a message in my app. The function called is going to my Java server and call a function like :

```
@POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response sendMsg(Message m) throws ExceptionFacade {
...
}
```

So each time I call this function I'd like to send a POST request to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send with a json.

I want to know if there is already a code ready for a java server ? and also some help how to implement it.

Also I don't understand if I can use a php file to do it (I find things like this https://github.com/Paragraph1/php-fcm ). I am using angularjs.

Thank you guys !

Comment: I don't think i understand. So you are asking how to send an http request in java?

Comment: Yes I think there is library for it ?

Comment: I mean doing the same POST request as I did in Postman but in java

Comment: There are a lot of resources available online. For example this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3325065/2633917

Comment: I have some troubles for import, import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;

Comment: and what are these troubles?

Comment: Well it is ok, now I doing the connection with gson/json and I put the answer if it works

Answer (score 4):

Here is the final code working well !
It is sending a json like this :

```
{
 "to" : "...",
 "priority" : "high",
 "notification" : {
                   "title" : "hello",
                   "body" : "me"
  }
}
```

//Don't forget to add common-codec and common-login jar for build success.

```
public class JavaApplication1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, IOException {

                HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
                post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                post.setHeader("Authorization", "key=FCM-API-KEY");
                JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
                message.put("to", "TOKEN-FCM-OF-THE-DEVICE");
                message.put("priority", "high");
                JSONObject notification = new JSONObject();
                notification.put("title", "Me");
                notification.put("body", "New message");
                message.put("notification", notification);
                post.setEntity(new StringEntity(message.toString(), "UTF-8"));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

                System.out.println(response);
                System.out.println(message);
    }
```