# How to send headers and data to URL for Firebase Cloud Messaging in Java

Tags: java, url, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging server in Java. How do I achieve adding headers such as `Content-Type`, `Authorization:key` as well as `JSON` data to the `Firebase Cloud Messaging` URL?
What I'm trying to achieve is from [this URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) and shown in the image below:
[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159704/java-server-send-push-with-post-to-google-firebase-cloud

Comment: made a mistake. the two items in my combo were the same n maybe thats why it returned index 0. when I changed the second item value things were ok @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Thanks for the update. In the future, please don't leave us in the lurch like this. Try to remember, that we're volunteers. If I put some thought, time and effort into trying to help figure something out, the least I deserve is closure or resolution on what caused the problem.