# Posting variable from java application to PHP

Tags: java, php, post

I am building a java application using Netbeans, I want to create a JButton to post a value from my application to a php file. 
I am applying the following code and it is not working:

```
private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

 try{
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/blow.php/");

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", "12/11/2016"));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

//Execute and get the response.
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

if (entity != null) {
    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
    try {
        // do something useful
    } finally {
        instream.close();
    }
}
        }catch(Exception w){
            System.err.println(w);}
// open file location and check 
String FolderName="http:\\localhost/blow.php";//Write your complete path here
try {
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + FolderName);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(blowing.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }      


    }
```

and in the php file only this is written:

```
 <?php

   $da=$_POST['date'];
   echo $da;

 ?>
```

Can you help with this please, thanks

Comment: Only this is written: ????? what is written? nothing?

Comment: You are missing your PHP code.

Comment: Sorry ! the php code : <?php $da=$_POST['date']; echo $da; ?>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16284863/2506641 The problem you have has nothing to do with php.

Comment: I am not receiving the POST

Comment: I think you have a typo in String FolderName="http:\\localhost/blow.php";//Write your complete path here it should be http:\\localhost/blow.php with slashes

Comment: the php file location is running it opens in the browser but there is no POST received

Comment: What is your intent with the second part of your code? (part that deals with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)`). What is the expected result?

Comment: First part posts the data to php; php echos the value `date` back in its response. But nothing is actually done with the response.

Comment: Also: How can you tell that on POST is received? (wireshark traces? php server logs?, etc...). What are the symptoms?