# Issues while passing XML request in java

Tags: java, xml, http

I need to send an xml request to a web service and accept xml response from that web service.

**Below is the Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String url ="http://XX.XXX.X.XX:80/test";
        String urlParameters = "";
        StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder(768);

        test.append("<?xml version='1.0'?>\n"+
    "<!DOCTYPE COMMAND PUBLIC '-//Ocam//DTD XML Command 1.0//EN' 'xml/command.dtd'>\n"+
                "<COMMAND>\n"+

                "<TYPE>EXUSRBALREQ</TYPE>\n"+
                "<DATE>14-03-17</DATE>\n"+
"<EXTNWCODE>MD</EXTNWCODE>\n"+
"<MSISDN>57625960</MSISDN>\n"+
"<PIN>47565</PIN>\n"+
"<LOGINID></LOGINID>\n"+
"<PASSWORD></PASSWORD>\n"+
"<EXTCODE>AD10001</EXTCODE>\n"+
"<EXTREFNUM>12345</EXTREFNUM>\n"+               
                "</COMMAND>\n");

        System.out.println(test);

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content_Type", "application/xml");          
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Sending post on the URL"+url);      
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();     
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }           
        in.close();

        System.out.println(responseCode);
        System.out.println(response);


    }
```

Whenever i run the application i am getting 200 status however below is the response which i get

**Response:**

```
Sending post on the URLhttp://XXX.XXX.X.XX:80/test
200
mclass^2&pid^61:6002:Your request is invalid.  Please call 8900
```

Can Somebody help me with this.

Regards,

Amit Gupta

Comment: You should ask the provider of the webservice. It looks like your request got through, but it is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks Neplatny for the reply , i did check with the provider however they have mentioned that the xml request is not reaching then hence they are sending that response, is there any way where i can trace the message which is going, currently i am performing this test on windows machine.

Comment: There is a typo in your code: The HTTP header is "Content-Type", not "Content_Type". That may be the problem.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense: "request is not reaching then hence they are sending that response". How can they send response when they don't receive a request? Anyway you can check what's going on using wireshark.

Comment: Hi Neplanty, I meant that they are not receiving the request in a proper format, i need to trace the request so that i can be sure that correct format is going

Comment: Ah, ok. Anyway someone already posted an answer. To check what' going on, use wireshark. It's the essential tool when debugging protocols.

Comment: Perhaps their web service is SOAP based, in which case, simple XML isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code assembles the XML to send in the `StringBuilder` called `test`.

However, you never actually send the contents of `test`, so it's not surprising the server does not receive the XML. Please fix that.

See for example [Sending HTTP POST Request In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java) for how to send a POST request in Java.

Comment: I rectified the Content-type as @sleske mentioned and i am getting response

Comment: however that is not an expected response, after going through wireshark as @Neplatny mentioned it looks like the request is not being passed, need to add the and then retry

Comment: Added  wr.write(test.getBytes()) , changed the request from Stringbuilder to String and when checked in wireshark the request is passing.