# Send messages using Slack Incoming webhooks

Tags: java, android, slack-api

I want to send a message in a channel in my slack workspace. I have seen many tutorials on how to use it but they are all in node.js, python but not java. Is there any way I could send a message at the slack channel #general when someone opens my app?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below steps:

1. First create your app for custom messages using this [URL](https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks#getting-started)
2. If you want to send messages in various beautiful layouts, follow this [link](https://api.slack.com/messaging/composing/layouts)
3. Sample working code for aforementioned layouts:

Code:

```
        List<LayoutBlock> message = new ArrayList<>();
        message.add(SectionBlock.builder()
            .text(MarkdownTextObject.builder().text("*"Subject of the message "*").build()).build());

message.add(
            SectionBlock
                    .builder().fields(
                            Arrays.asList(
                                    MarkdownTextObject.builder()
                                            .text("*First Topic:* "Your text")
                                            .build(),
MarkdownTextObject.builder().text("*Second topic:* "Your text ").build())).build());

message.add(DividerBlock.builder().build());

ChatPostMessageRequest request = ChatPostMessageRequest.builder().channel("Your Slack Channel ID").blocks(message)
            .build();
ChatPostMessageResponse response = methodsClient.chatPostMessage(request);
response.getChannel();
```

PS: If you want to add any link in your message:

```
MarkdownTextObject.builder().text("*Link Text:* <"https://.."|click here>").build()
```

Note: You can edit the layout as per your ease, [refer this url](https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/T033N74ES4U#%7B%22blocks%22:%5B%7B%22type%22:%22header%22,%22text%22:%7B%22type%22:%22plain_text%22,%22text%22:%22New%20request%22,%22emoji%22:true%7D%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22section%22,%22fields%22:%5B%7B%22type%22:%22mrkdwn%22,%22text%22:%22*Type:*%5CnPaid%20Time%20Off%22%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22mrkdwn%22,%22text%22:%22*Created%20by:*%5Cn%3Cexample.com%7CFred%20Enriquez%3E%22%7D%5D%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22section%22,%22fields%22:%5B%7B%22type%22:%22mrkdwn%22,%22text%22:%22*When:*%5CnAug%2010%20-%20Aug%2013%22%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22mrkdwn%22,%22text%22:%22*Type:*%5CnPaid%20time%20off%22%7D%5D%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22section%22,%22fields%22:%5B%7B%22type%22:%22mrkdwn%22,%22text%22:%22*Hours:*%5Cn16.0%20(2%20days)%22%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22mrkdwn%22,%22text%22:%22*Remaining%20balance:*%5Cn32.0%20hours%20(4%20days)%22%7D%5D%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22section%22,%22text%22:%7B%22type%22:%22mrkdwn%22,%22text%22:%22%3Chttps://example.com%7CView%20request%3E%22%7D%7D%5D%7D)

Answer (score 0):

Incoming webhooks on Slack are very easy to use and basically work with any programming language / platform as long as you are able to send a HTTP POST request.

First I would recommend to check out the [excellent documentation](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks#getting-started) with step-by-step instructions on how to get started with webhooks.

Then to get the feel for how webhooks I would advise playing around with it using tools like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/).

Last but not least: if you want to learn how to make a HTTP POST request in Java, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java).

Comment: Thanks! Also, I can use the HTTP POST to use discord webhooks as well? (sorry for being a noob)

Comment: yes. Discord webhooks work similar and you can also use HTTP POST requests to use them. See the documentation for it here: https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook

Comment: Cool, ill try it and I will ask if I have any problems, thanks for your help