# Send HTTP post with the given Request body and headers and get the respone

Tags: java, http, post, request

My question is that how i send http post to a server with request body and headers and get the *response code*  and also get *response content in String* format

**post url**

```
http://192.168.1.2/default/en_US/sms_info.html?type=sms
```

**request body**

```
action:sms
send:send
line1:1
line2:1
line3:1
smscontent:im sending you this message from website
telnum:03459347900
```

**headers**

```
Origin:http://192.168.8.1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization:Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
```

Comment: Plenty of tutorials out there, what have you tried?

Comment: i tried each answer of this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java

Comment: And whats the problem? Paste what you've tried and maybe then we can help.

Comment: but i dint find any answer in which headers and request used

Comment: actually i'm kind a noob, i need a chunk of java code send http post to the mentioned url, with mentioned request perameters and along with headers

Comment: Well, you will not get *a chunk of java code* written for your on S.O

Comment: can you give me any direction ?? which can help me??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609231/get-post-requst-to-rest-api-using-spring-boot/52609744#52609744

Comment: @parladneupane in this answer, they used rawData for request body but i have key value format, of request body not a raw format

Comment: hey it is just a data they want to send if you do not have any data , then leave it empty.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or any other HTTP client.