# In postman api works fine but in java it doesn't

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, postman

I am trying to get a JSON Object from an API while using an API Url. This works perfectly when I test it in Postman, but when I try it in my Spring application, it returns 405 with message(The method is not allowed for the requested URL)

My Java Code:-

```
URL tokenURL = new URL("https://something.in/v1/token");
HttpURLConnection tokenConnection = (HttpURLConnection) tokenURL.openConnection();
tokenConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
tokenConnection.setConnectTimeout(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty
    ("common.webServiceCall.maxTimeOut")));
tokenConnection.setReadTimeout(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty
    ("common.webServiceCall.maxTimeOut")));
tokenConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
tokenConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
tokenConnection.setRequestProperty("X-IBM-Client-Id", "45878d21-469c-b68e-34b1suds34c");
tokenConnection.setRequestProperty("X-IBM-Client-Secret", "ytGThJH4sW7hY2skhJHG65uC7xH7v645fsdfkjgFGHDFgcvhg");
tokenConnection.setDoInput(true);
tokenConnection.setDoOutput(true);  
OutputStream tokenStream = null;
try {
    tokenStream = tokenConnection.getOutputStream();
} catch (RemoteException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        tokenConnection.connect();
            if (tokenConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                break;
            }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (tokenConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((tokenConnection.getInputStream())));
    StringBuilder serviceResponse = new StringBuilder();
    String serviceResponseLine;
    while ((serviceResponseLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        serviceResponse.append(serviceResponseLine);
    }
    tokenStream.close();
    tokenConnection.disconnect();
    System.out.println(serviceResponse);
} else {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((tokenConnection.getErrorStream())));
    StringBuilder serviceResponse = new StringBuilder();
    String serviceResponseLine;
    while ((serviceResponseLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        serviceResponse.append(serviceResponseLine);
    }
    tokenStream.close();
    tokenConnection.disconnect();
    System.out.println(serviceResponse);
}
```

Comment: What are those 19 headers?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca that came in response

Comment: Ok, so why are you showing us the response instead of the request?

Comment: because there is no request only the url, the body is empty..@FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: How does the API know who you are? It just gives away tokens without authenticating? What's the point?

Comment: POST request can carry data in body

Comment: No I have the client Id & key for that and I've included in java code `tokenConnection.setRequestProperty("id","clientId")` and `tokenConnection.setRequestProperty("key","clientkey")` @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: The url will only on `GET` method and no other @btreport

Comment: Can you try to generate a curl request from the postman and trigger it from terminal ? (Sometimes postman adds headers by itsown, and you might be missing it in the code)

Comment: Remove : setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); and try, generally its use to make POST call

Comment: nope, didn't work @btreport

Comment: I've edited the post please have a look @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: @Cybertronian they're still not matching (header names). Is the code you posted the actual code you're using? (barring secrets, of course)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca So I've included actual id and key and for clearance the response message that I'm receiving from java code is `{ "httpCode":"405", "httpMessage":"Method Not Allowed", "moreInformation":"The method is not allowed for the requested URL" }`

Comment: Well, your Java code is doing a POST. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587913/what-exactly-does-urlconnection-setdooutput-affect You want a GET, right?

Comment: yes I want a `Get` and how do i acquire it..? @Thilo

Comment: And doesn't Spring Boot come with a reasonable HTTP Client so that you don't have to write 20 lines just to do a simple GET request?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609231/get-post-requst-to-rest-api-using-spring-boot

Comment: Thank you very much! @Thilo I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

I have one suggestion, postman can generate source code of request for different programming languages e.g. java and JavaScript and command line tool like cURL.
I suggest use cURL gives you more verbose details that can help you in connection configuration.

[image]