# Java doesn't send HTTP POST Request

Tags: java, http, post

I'm implementing some simple java class in order to send an `HTTP` Request with `POST` method and also another java class in order to receive it.
The server works fine when I make a `POST` request by means of my browser(Chrome), or an application(I have used Postman in this case) but it ends up with problem when I send `HTTP` Request with java!

My sending `HTTP` class is "Sender.java", containing the following snippet:

```
String url = "http://localhost:8082/";
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

// Setting basic post request
con.setRequestMethod("POST");       
//con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
//con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/plain");

// Send post request
con.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
os.write("Just Some Text".getBytes("UTF-8"));
os.flush();
os.close();
//connect to the Server(resides at Server.java)
con.connect();
```

I have commented some lines of code setting Headers like "Accept-Language" and "Content-Type" because I don't know whether or not are these headers required for the java program to work out?

The server is another java program named "Server.java". Here is the snippet related to reading `HTTP` Request made by the Sender.java(if need be).

```
int servPort = 8082;
// Create a server socket to accept HTTP client connection requests
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(servPort), 0);
System.out.println("server started at " + servPort);

server.createContext("/", new PostHandler());//PostHandler implements HttpHandler
server.setExecutor(null);

server.start();
```

All I want is to send a plaintext as the body of my `HTTP` Request with the `Post` method. I have read plenty of sites and even related questions at this site. But it still doesn't work out. In other words, whenever I create an `HTTP` Request from "Sender.java", nothing appears at "Server.java". I just want to know what's wrong with my snippets and how should I fix that?

Comment: What error do you get in Java? Is it simply not received? What actually happens?

Comment: Have you used a network analysis tool such as Wireshark to see what (if anything) is actually being sent across the sockets?

Comment: There is no Error. The problem is nothing happens! I expect the HTTP Post to be sent by Sender.java and read by Server.java, as in the case of my browser or Postman.

Comment: @JoeC let's check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this and it's working:

```
//Sender.java
String url = "http://localhost:8082/";
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();


con.setRequestMethod("POST");       
con.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
os.write("Just Some Text".getBytes("UTF-8"));
os.flush();

int httpResult = con.getResponseCode(); 
con.disconnect();
```

As you can see, **connect** is not necessary. The key line is

> int httpResult = con.getResponseCode();

Comment: This answer doesn't encode anything. Would lead to problems. Use Ferrybig's answer.

Comment: Don't forget to flush =)))

Answer (score 1):

When you send a POST form using the browser, it sends the form in a certain format, defined in [RFC1866](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866#section-8.2.1), you have to recreate this on Java when making a post request.

With this format, its important you set the `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and pass the body as you would do in a url with a get request.

[Borrowing some code of my previous answer to POST in Java:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35013372/1542723)

```
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

// Setting basic post request
con.setRequestMethod("POST");    

Map<String,String> form = new HashMap<>();

// Define the fields
form.put("username", "root");
form.put("password", "sjh76HSn!"); // This is a fake password obviously

// Build the body
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner("&");
for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : arguments.entrySet())
    sj.add(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8") + "=" 
         + URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
byte[] out = sj.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
int length = out.length;

// Prepare our `con` object
con.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(length);
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
con.connect();
try (OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream()) {
    os.write(out);
}
```

Comment: This is the answer! Fixed my issues. Thank you. It's very important to encode the post body correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe “localhost” in the sender url does not resolve to the same ip that the server binds to? Try changing to 127.0.0.1 or your actual IP address.

Comment: hmm is it the exact same URL and/or IP in Sender.java as it is in POSTMAN/Chrome?

Comment: Yes. The exact URL and exact Port. The problem was entitled by not invoking the getResponseCode() : "int httpResult = con.getResponseCode();". I don't know why but It worked when I added this line, due to  what aka-one said

Answer (score 0):

try with PrintStream

```
        String url = "http://localhost:8082/";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // Setting basic post request
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");       
        //con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        //con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/plain");

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        java.io.PrintStream printStream = new java.io.PrintStream(os);
        printStream.println("Just Some Text");
        con.getInputStream();//Send request
        os.flush();
        os.close();
```