# Send post request with body in java

Tags: java, post

I am having some problems sending a POST request in java to a local server. I tested this local server with Postman and it is indeed working as it should. Sadly when i try sending the POST requst in java, everything goes as it should with 200 OK code, BUT there is nothing in the body. This is my code:

```
public static void request1() throws MalformedURLException, ProtocolException, IOException {                

    URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.200");
    HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
    httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");

    OutputStream os = httpCon.getOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");       
    osw.write("Just Some Text");
    osw.flush();
    osw.close();
    os.close();  //don't forget to close the OutputStream
    httpCon.connect();  
    System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseCode());
    System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseMessage());

}
```

EDIT: i see some of you said that this is a duplicate and gave me another link where it is supposed to be solved. Sadly i tried the code from that link and it is not working. Server simply says that the request has no body.

Comment: You mean you dont see local server response body?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java doesn't send HTTP POST Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52975002/java-doesnt-send-http-post-request)

Answer (score 1):

From the `HttpUrlConnection#getResponseMessage` JavaDoc:

> Gets the HTTP response message, if any, returned along with the
>   response code from a server.
>   From responses like:
>   HTTP/1.0 200 OK
>   HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
>   Extracts the Strings "OK" and "Not Found"
>   respectively. Returns null if none could be discerned from the responses (the result was not valid HTTP).

If you want the response body, you need to extract it from the `HttpUrlConnection` `InputStream`.

You may use `HttpUrlConnection#getInputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the actual response body you need to read it from,

```
httpCon.getInputStream()
```

You may read the data in a string with a one liner like this,

```
String responseBody = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpCon.getInputStream())).lines().collect(
        Collectors.joining("\n"));
System.out.println(responseBody);
```