# HttpPost add to url HTTP/1.1

Tags: java, spring, post, apache-httpclient-4.x, fluent

This void for creating the POST.

```
public void doPostRequest(Object input, String methodName) throws IOException {
        try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
            String JSON_STRING = writer.writeValueAsString(input);

            StringEntity requestEntity = new StringEntity(
                    JSON_STRING,
                    ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);

            HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(methodName);
            postMethod.setEntity(requestEntity);
            HttpResponse rawResponse = httpClient.execute(postMethod);
        }

    }
```

methodName - its String like:

```
http://myservice:8180/location-service/add
```

but my postMethod will become after initializing:

```
http://myservice:8180/location-service/sync_api/add HTTP/1.1
```

what is HTTP/1.1 ? and how can I delete it??

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java

Comment: i need to use JSON_STRING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print `postMethod`, you see:

`POST http://myservice:8180/location-service/add HTTP/1.1`

`HTTP/1.1` is a part of every `HTTP` request structure. `HTTP/1.1` show that this request is based on `1.1` version of `HTTP`. This is not part of your API address (`/location-service/add`).

This is an example of a `POST` request:

```
POST /test/demo_form.php HTTP/1.1
Host: w3schools.com
name1=value1&name2=value2
```