# Java send http post with interceptor

Tags: java, http, post

I want to send http post with interceptor ,include header( cookies ...etc) and body  .I test it OK with post man ( require enable add on interceptor in chrome). How can i send http post with java code.Please help me.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending HTTP POST Request In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java)

Comment: As of Java 11, the apache HTTP Client is included in the JDK. With earlier version, use HttpUrlConnection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send a POST request to a URL you just need an HTTP library. A common one is [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/). Example straight from their [site](https://square.github.io/okhttp/):

```java
public static final MediaType JSON
    = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
  RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .post(body)
      .build();
  try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
    return response.body().string();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Noctem,How can i add header and body.In your answer i only see body json ?