# How to get JSON data from solar winds Orion rest API using java

Tags: java, json, rest, solarwinds-orion

I want to get the JSON data from solarwinds orion rest api and have to write those JSON data in excel file.

Comment: Please share what all things have you tried?

Comment: Hi Abhi, I just tried the some solarwinds orion rest  request to get cpu load and memmory load for specific start time and end time trough POSTMAN. https://github.com/solarwinds/OrionSDK/wiki/REST 
POST "BulkUpdate Request"

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you need a java program to send a post request to an API endpoint. ApacheHTTP library to the rescue. You can read more from the documentation [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e37). Even more information in the [official apache website](http://hc.apache.org/)

```java
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.a-domain.com/foo/");

// Request parameters and other properties.
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param-1", "12345"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param-2", "Hello!"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

//Execute and get the response.
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

if (entity != null) {
    try (InputStream instream = entity.getContent()) {
        // do something useful
    }
}
```

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java) answer

Comment: Hi @Sanjay this is not that case.Couldn't find the exact rest api request for soladwinds orion cpu load and memory load for some period of time.

Comment: You want to know which API to use?

Comment: Yes,orion request template.