# Redirect to external url with post attributes using spring MVC

Tags: spring-boot, redirect, response.redirect, post-redirect-get

I am facing issue in getting attributes after redirecting in external url. 
I am getting attributes values as null when redirecting to external url where as If I put these method in same webapp It works.

Please suggest what I am doing wrong, or if there is any way, so that I can pass attribute to redirected url and use It.

I don't want attributes to be shown as Queryparams.

sample code is as below.

//Controller in app1

```
@PostMapping("/redirect")
public RedirectView next(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Model model, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {
    request.setAttribute("payment",new Payment("1","2","3"));
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("test", "test");

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Successfully changed..");
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("payment1",new Payment("1","2","3"));

    request.setAttribute(
              View.RESPONSE_STATUS_ATTRIBUTE, HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
    RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("redirect:http://localhost:8085/redirectedPostToPost", true);
    redirectView.addStaticAttribute("payment",new Payment("1","2","3"));
    return redirectView;
}
```

//Controller of app2.

```
@PostMapping("/redirectedPostToPost")
public ModelAndView redirectedPostToPost(@ModelAttribute("message") String message,@ModelAttribute("payment") Payment payment,@ModelAttribute("payment1") Payment payment1, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,Model model, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, HttpServletRequest request, ModelAndView modelview) {
    logger.info("in redirectedPostToPost:{} : modelview:{}", model, modelview.getModel());
    Map<String, ?> inputFlashMap = RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request);
    logger.info("flashmap:{}", inputFlashMap);
    return new ModelAndView("about");
}
```

Thanking you guys in advance.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP support only GET method redirect. here is details [why doesn't HTTP have POST redirect](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect)

There is a workaround you send data to view and create the FORM in the view you should use all hidden field for data to submit. it will be a white page. You can automatically submit the form redirect URL using the javascript.

Comment: If I do so, what happens if on automatic form submit  it redirects to another page and on clicking back button of browser to go one step back (previous url) it will redirect again ? wouldn't this issue arise If I do so?

Comment: yes, it will redirect again if user click the back button

Comment: Here it is another possible solution to submit internally using HttpClient  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java