# https POST call in java

Tags: java, https

How to call the following POST call in JAVA

```
curl -X "POST" "https://<url>" -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -u 'password'
```

Comment: see this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-implement-get-and-post-request-through-simp