# I want to create a user on Duo Admin API but I don't know that I am doing wrong. Can anyone guide me?

Tags: java, rest, two-factor-authentication, google-duo

I am trying to solve this problem but I don't know what am I doing wrong?

Here is the documentation https://duo.com/docs/adminapi#create-user

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

public class duo {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
// Create a neat value object to hold the URL

  URL url;
      url = new URL("?Authorization =Basic&Integration key: Secret key=DILV:DLr5bzSztv&Date=Sat, 14 Aug 2021 02:19:40 +0000&Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded=api-e9770554.duosecurity.com&=/admin/v1/users&=username=xyz");



// Open a connection(?) on the URL(??) and cast the response(???)
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// Now it's "open", we can set the request method, headers etc.
        connection.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");

// This line makes the request
        InputStream responseStream = connection.getInputStream();

 }

}
```

**Error**

```
{
    "code": 40401,
    "message": "Resource not found",
    "stat": "FAIL"
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you're actually trying to retrieve an existing user, and the system is telling you that user does not exist.

Comment: I have updated the url. I want to create user.

Comment: I don't see where you're doing a POST, as the documentation requires.  Try the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3325065).

Comment: I did post on Postman tool to check the response but I am still getting the same error. This is the url "POSThttps://api-e9770554.duosecurity.com/admin/v1/users"

Comment: Well, are you setting up all of the required parameters correctly?

Comment: How are you specifying `username`, the sole required parameter?

Comment: Updated the url please check